# How to select all specific elements with all siblings of a specific element

Tags: jquery

Trying to select all h2's, this works fine. However, sometimes my h2's can have siblings of h3's that i also want to select.

For example, i have:

`<h2>

<h3>

<h3>

<h3>

<h2>

<h2>

<h2>

<h3>

<h3>`

http://jsfiddle.net/v9upc/1/ is my current code, and here is an example of What i'm trying to achieve is:

`-<h2>

--<h3>

--<h3>

--<h3>

-<h2>

-<h2>

-<h2>

--<h3>

--<h3>`

How do I select all the h2's and if they siblings h3's to include them as children in the unordered list?

Comment: what is the problem with the current code

Comment: It is selecting all h3s and appending them to all the h2s regardless if the h2 has a sibling h3 or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $h2s = $('h2'), $div = $h2s.parent();
var toTop = '<span class="top">Back to top</span>';

var $ct = $('<div />', {
    class: 'indexholder'
}).append('<h2>On this page</h2>');

var $ul = $('<ul />', {
    class: 'index'
}).appendTo($ct);

$h2s.each(function(idx, el){
    var $li = $('<li />', {
        id: 'index' + idx,
        text: $(this).text()
    }).appendTo($ul);

    var $h3s = $(this).nextUntil('h2', 'h3');
    if($h3s.length){
        var $l1ul = $('<ul />', {
        }).appendTo($li);

        $h3s.each(function(idx2, el2){
            var $li = $('<li />', {
                text: $(this).text()
            }).appendTo($l1ul);
        })        
    }
})

$div.replaceWith($ct)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QWZWE/)